# Failing to Assign values to Model/class memebers before Passing it to the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Model class as follows:

```
namespace newWorld
{
    public class oneWorld
    {
        //There is no direct property defined 

        public struct Work              // struct
        {
            public int WorkID;

            public int PersonID;

            public newWorld.Person.Area.person p1;
            public List<Favourite> fav;
        }
         public struct Favourite
        {
            public string chocolate {get; set;}
            public string dress {get; set;}
        }
     }
}
```

=========================================
I want to access this class in controller action method so that I can assign values to list "fav" inside struct work, and access the properties and other variables and methods inside this class. HOW do i do that?

because when I do the following, inside action method:

newWorld.oneWorld obj=new newWorld.oneWorld();
obj.     // does not expose anything

Comment: What do you mean it _does not expose anything_? It exposes the `Name` property (which is the only property in the class) - you can do `object.Name = "xxxx";`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, But I am focusing on list called fav and the structs declared... I want to access them and assign values to those structs and the members inside them specifically.. How do i do that? Obj is not exposing any struct or anything... Sorry for that property Name.. it shouldn't be there.

Comment: You need properties for them. All you have at the moment are nested `struct`s (why are you making them `struct` and why nested?). Add properties to the class - `public Work Worker { get; set; }` (because of the nested `struct`, you will not be able to name the property `Work`)

Comment: its a project already built,in web forms & I am migrating it as it is.I believe,I can't make changes to it.I just need to access and work upon these classes/instances. @StephenMuecke
2. And also,if you notice,they are two different structs containing diff. sets of properties within them. It may be written with an intention to use only struct 1 at some places and struct 2 at places where required..otherwise, declaring all the properties directly into the class will make it heavier and when we would need only a particular set of properties we would have to load all the properties instead.

Comment: If you don't add a property for the struct, then you cant access it! Alternatively you will need to do `newWorld.oneWorld.Work obj= new newWorld.oneWorld.Work(); object.WorkID = someValue;` But having a class with no properties and no methods is nonsense

Comment: Property for the struct!!!!!! there are already properties within the structs. I meant, there would be no properties in the class. Instead it has multiple methods and struct and enum declared inside this class. How do I access them at its instance???

Comment: OMG. Your class has **NO** properties. Read my previous comments!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89122/discussion-between-svik-and-stephen-muecke).